# Fill the area enclosed by multiple functions in a single plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to fill the area enclosed by four functions, as indicated by the hatching in red in the figure below:

[image]

So far I've been able to fill the area between each pair of functions, as shown below:

[image]

The first was produced as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun1}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ tan(x)/( cos(x)*( 1 + 3.3*((tan(x))^2) ) ) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun2}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 1.1*tan(x)*(1/cos(x)) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun3}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 0.145*( ( 1 + 3.3*(tan(x))^2 ) / sin(x) ) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun4}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 4 }}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
width=7cm,height=11cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=90,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.1, ymax=10,
ymajorgrids,yminorgrids]

% fun1 (start stacking)
\addplot[
domain=1:25.70,
draw=none,fill=none,mark=none,
stack plots=y]
{ fun1 };
%
% stack difference between fun2 and fun1 on top of fun1
\addplot[
domain=1:25.70,
draw=none,draw opacity=0.0,
fill=gray,fill opacity=0.25,
stack plots=y
]
{ max( fun2 - fun1 , 0 ) }
\closedcycle;

% fun1
\addplot[domain=1:89,solid,line width=0.8pt,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun1 };

% fun2 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:25.78,solid,line width=0.8pt,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun2 };
% fun2 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=25.78:89,dashed,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun2 };

% fun3 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:89,dashed,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun3 };
% fun3 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=25.78:70,solid,line width=0.8pt,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun3 };
% fun3 (branch 3)
\addplot[domain=70:89,dashed,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun3 };

% fun4 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:70,dashed,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun4 };
% fun4 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=70:89,solid,line width=0.8pt,draw=black,mark=none]{ fun4 };

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The 2nd and 3rd were obtained, respectively, using:

- `domain=25.78:70` and `{ max( fun3 - fun1 , 0 ) }`
- `domain=70:89` and `{ max( fun4 - fun1 , 0 ) }`

How can I display them on a single plot?

Comment: If what you want is combining three plots into one `tikzpicture`, I don't see how the current title (*Fill the area enclosed by multiple functions*) is descriptive of the problem at all...

Comment: @Jubobs feel free to edit the title, or otherwise suggest a more appropriate one.

Comment: @nnunnes Oops. Sorry; I had completely misunderstood your question. I'll scrap my answer. Your lastest edit helps a lot in clarifying the question, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a new piecewise function fun5(x) combining fun2, fun3 and fun4 and fill the area between fun1 and fun5:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun1}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{tan(#1)/(cos(#1)*(1+3.3*((tan(#1))^2)))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun2}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1.1*tan(#1)*(1/cos(#1))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun3}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{0.145*((1+3.3*(tan(#1))^2)/sin(#1))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun4}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{4}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun5}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (#1>=1 && #1<=25.78)*fun2(#1) +%
    (#1>25.78 && #1<=70)*fun3(#1) +%
    (#1>70 && #1<89)*fun4(#1)}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
width=7cm,height=11cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=90,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.1, ymax=10,
ymajorgrids,yminorgrids]
% area
\addplot [domain=1:89,draw=none,stack plots=y]
         {fun1(x)};
%         
\addplot [domain=1:89,draw=none,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.25,stack plots=y]
         {max(fun5(x) - fun1(x),0)}
\closedcycle;
%
% fun1
\addplot [domain=1:89,line width=0.8pt] {fun1(x)};
% fun2 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:25.78,solid,line width=0.8pt]{fun2(x)};
% fun2 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=25.78:89,dashed]{fun2(x)};
%
% fun3 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:89,dashed]{fun3(x)};
% fun3 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=25.78:70,line width=0.8pt]{fun3(x)};
% fun3 (branch 3)
\addplot[domain=70:89,dashed]{fun3(x)};
%
% fun4 (branch 1)
\addplot[domain=1:70,dashed]{fun4(x)};
% fun4 (branch 2)
\addplot[domain=70:89,line width=0.8pt]{fun4(x)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Version 1.10 of pgfplots has been released just recently, and it comes with a new solution for the problem to fill the area between plots.

Note that the old solution is still possible and still valid; this here is merely an update which might simplify the task. In order to keep the knowledge base of this site up-to-date, I present a solution based on the new `fillbetween` library here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun1}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ tan(x)/( cos(x)*( 1 + 3.3*((tan(x))^2) ) ) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun2}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 1.1*tan(x)*(1/cos(x)) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun3}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 0.145*( ( 1 + 3.3*(tan(x))^2 ) / sin(x) ) }}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fun4}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ 4 }}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
width=7cm,height=11cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=90,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.1, ymax=10,
ymajorgrids,yminorgrids]


% fun1
\addplot[name path=fun1,domain=1:89,red]{ fun1 };

% fun2 
\addplot[name path=fun2,domain=1:78.89,blue]{ fun2 };

% fun3 
\addplot[name path=fun3,domain=1:89,brown,]{ fun3 };

% fun4 
\addplot[name path=fun4,domain=1:89,orange]{ fun4 };

\path[name path=intermediate,
     %draw, line width=2pt,
    intersection segments={of=fun2 and fun3,
        sequence=A0 -- B1,
    },
];
\path[name path=segments,
    %draw, line width=2pt,
    intersection segments={of=intermediate and fun4,
        sequence=A0 -- B1,
    },
];

\addplot[gray,fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of=segments and fun1];
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This solution just has the four functions without any modifications. However, it assigns a label to each of them. Then, we have to `\path` instructions which compute intersection segments: the first `\path` instruction generates an intermediate path which will be discarded. Note that `\path` without `draw` or `fill` has no visible output (and generates only scopes in the resulting pdf, no path instructions). The first `intermediate` path consists of the `intersection segments` of `fun2 and fun3`, namely the segments `A0` which means "first (0th) segment of the first argument (`fun2`)". Graphically, this is the lower left edge of the filled region (blue and brown). The first argument is always called `A` in this context, segment indices start at 0. This segment is connected with `B1` which means the second (1st) segment of the second argument in `of=fun2 and fun3` (i.e. the second segment of `fun3`).

The second `\path` instruction computes `intersection segments` of `intermediate and fun4`. Keep in mind that `fun4` is the top path (the orange one). Here, we take `A0` (the first intersection segment of `intermediate`) and connect it with `B1` (the second = 1st segment of `fun4`).

Both of these `\path` instructions result in no visible output (unless you insert the uncomment `draw` keys). They only store the results under a name.

Finally, the last `\addplot fill between` statement fills the area between our computed `segments` and `fun1`. To this end, it uses the fill options `gray,fill opacity=0.25`.