# Area restricted by three functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to shade the area restricted by the functions
`y \sin x`, `x = \sin y` and `y = 2pi + x`. Now my problem is that
I do not have access to `Pgfplots 1.10`so the libary `fillbetween` is not accessible to me. I have attempted to plot the area below using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0,0.99)},
anchor=north west}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2.5*pi,xmax=pi,ymin=-pi,ymax=2.5*pi,
    domain=-2pi:2pi,
    samples=100,
    xlabel={$x$},  
    ylabel={$y$},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    axis lines=middle
]
\addlegendentry{$y =x + 2\pi$}
\addplot[black,thick,black,domain=-2*pi:0] {x+2*pi} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=gray,opacity=0.1,thick,black,domain=-2*pi:0] {x+2*pi} \closedcycle;

\addplot[color=red,fill= white,thick,domain=-2*pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[color=blue,fill= white,thick,variable=\t, domain=0:2*pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});

\addplot[color=red,fill=gray,opacity=0.2,thick,domain=-pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[color=blue,fill=gray,opacity=0.2,thick,variable=\t, domain=0:pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});

\addlegendentry{$y =x + 2\pi$}
\addplot[color=red,thick,domain=-2*pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$y =x + 2\pi$}
\addplot[color=blue,thick,variable=\t, domain=0:2*pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});
%\addlegendentry{$x = \sin y$}
]\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TheBowler]

I have tried to mark the parts on the figure I am having problems with. All
of them are related to how I am shading the figure. The idea I am using is to
first fill in the entire triangular area under `x + 2\pi`, and then fill in white where needed.

- Why must i use `opacity=0.1` for the first function and `opacity=0.2` 
  for the second function to obtain the same color gray? Is this a problem on my end?
- Why is the `x-axis` unneven, eg higher between -pi and 0 ? Same with `y-axis`.
- Labels, why are the first and last label correct, but the middle one is always gray?

I think the labeling problem is a minor problem caused by how I fill the various parts of the figure. But still it is quite weird that the first and second legends are fine. 
So to summarize, is there a better method for shading the area gray? I have tried the method provided here [filling area between 2 functions, with shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34102/filling-area-between-2-functions-with-shading), but alas this crashes every time I try to invoke the sine function, and not sure how to handle the implicit function using this method.

Comment: Something like the TikZ `\clip` command might help you, but I’m away from a TeX compiler and so I can’t try it right now.

Comment: Although explicitly stated that `pgfplots 1.10` with its `fillbetween` library is not an option, I would like to give pointers to a related solution in order to build up the knowledge base: http://texwelt.de/wissen/antwort_link/4161/ (in german)  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112738/fill-the-area-enclosed-by-multiple-functions-in-a-single-plot/163659#163659

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your three points briefly:

- There is an extra `black` after the in the first function. I suppose this overrides the defined `fill` colour (`gray`), and `black` with `opacity=0.1` is about the same as `gray` with `opacity=0.2`.
- It is because of the filling I think, which covers up half of the axis width. For `x < -pi/2`  the top half is covered, for `x > -pi/2` the bottom half is covered, leading to the small 'step'. You can fix this by placing the fill on the background layer.
- `\addlegendentry` picks up the plots in the order they are defined, regardless of where they are placed, so it is the first three `\addplots` that are shown in the legend. The `forget plot` key removes a plot from the legend I believe.

You have a spurious `]` just before  `\end{axis}` by the way.

In the code below I plot the lines first, then add the fill on the background layer using the `backgrounds` library from TikZ.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0,0.99)},
anchor=north west},
cells={anchor=west}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-2.5*pi,xmax=pi,ymin=-pi,ymax=2.5*pi,
    domain=-2pi:2pi,
    samples=100,
    xlabel={$x$},  
    ylabel={$y$},
    yticklabels={,,},
    xticklabels={,,},
    axis lines=middle
]

\addplot[draw=black,thick,domain=-2*pi:0] {x+2*pi};
\addplot[draw=red,thick,domain=-2*pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[draw=blue,thick,variable=\t, domain=0:2*pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});
\addlegendentry{$y = x + 2\pi$}
\addlegendentry{$y = \sin x$}
\addlegendentry{$x = \sin y$}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\addplot[draw=none,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2,domain=-2*pi:0] {x+2*pi} \closedcycle;
\addplot[draw=none,fill= white,domain=-2*pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[draw=none,fill= white,variable=\t, domain=0:2*pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});
\addplot[draw=none,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2,thick,domain=-pi:0] {sin(deg(x))};
\addplot[draw=none,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2,thick,variable=\t, domain=0:pi] ({sin(deg(t))}, {t});
\end{scope}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]